How to to navigate to another screen on Card click in React Native?
I have created 4 cards ; two in each row. I have added data in array. What I want to do is when i click these Cards, I want to navigate to another Screens, for example if i click on Card with id 1, I want to go to Screen A and then followed Cards 2,3,4 going to Screens B,C,D. Below is my code. I am relatively new to RN and Javascript. So, I am not sure how i can use Switch Statement here.
Home.js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles/Cardstyle';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

const data = [
{id: 1, title: 'Take a Test', image: require('./images/test.png')},
{id: 2, title: 'Questions', image: require('./images/questions.png')},
{id: 3, title: 'Instagram', image: require('./images/instagram.png')},
{id: 4, title: 'Telegram', image: require('./images/telegram.png')},
];

const Card = ({item}) => {
return (
<View style={styles.card}>
  <Image source={item.image} style={styles.cardImage} />
  <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
</View>
);
};

function Home() {
return (
<LinearGradient
  colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
  start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
  end={{x: 1, y: 1}}
  style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.aboveText}>Select an option</Text>
    <View style={styles.row}>
      {data.map(item => (
        <Card key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </View>
  </View>
</LinearGradient>
);
}
export default Home;`

Below is the style file
CardStyle.js
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const window = Dimensions.get('window'); // Get screen dimensions

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1, // Make container take all available space
padding: 20, // Add equal padding from all sides
justifyContent: 'center', // Center content vertically
alignItems: 'center',
alignContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
},
gradientBackground: {
flex: 1,
width: window.width, // Set width to screen width
height: window.height, // Set height to screen height
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
},
row: {
flexDirection: 'row',
flexWrap: 'wrap',
justifyContent: 'space-between', // Distribute cards evenly
marginBottom: 5,
},
card: {
width: '45%', // Adjust width based on your needs
height: '45%',
marginBottom: 40,
backgroundColor: '#eeeeee', // Change to your desired background color
borderRadius: 5,
alignItems: 'center',
},
cardImage: {
width: '70%',
height: 100, // Adjust height as needed
resizeMode: 'contain', // Fit image within container
justifyContent: 'center',
marginTop: 60,
},
cardTitle: {
marginTop: 10,
fontSize: 20,
marginBottom: 5,
fontStyle: 'normal',
},
aboveText: {
// Add this style for the above text
fontSize: 20, // Adjust font size as needed
marginBottom: 15,
fontStyle: 'normal',
color: '#ffffff',
},
});

export default styles;`
I want to apply onPressable to the Card but not sure how to use Switch here.
I understand there are 4 different cases and I have to use Switch statement but i am not sure how I can use it here
